# After configure apache2 for django website it shows apache default page on browser

Tags: django, apache, python-3.x, ubuntu, mod-wsgi

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.\
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /static /root/myproject/static
<Directory /root/myproject/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /root/myproject/myproject>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-path=/root/myproject python-home=/root/myproject/myprojectenv
WSGIProcessGroup myproject
WSGIScriptAlias /myproject /root/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

Above is my 000-default.conf apache2 file.

I have configured it for my django project named myproject and it is in root directory. And my virtualenv for this project is myprojectenv inside of myproject directory.

Comment: This site is mounted under /myproject. What URL are you going to to see it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, I made a silly mistake. When I put my project inside of www directory and reconfigure 000-default.conf according to it.
Just changed project path in apache file.

And now it started working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.example.com #your server name
    ServerAlias dev.example.com #your server alias

    DocumentRoot #your document root
    WSGIProcessGroup dev.example.com
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    WSGIDaemonProcess dev.example.com python-home=/home/robert/django/robertenv python-path=/home/robert/django/
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/robert/django/project/wsgi.py process-group=dev.example.com

    Alias "/uploads" "/home/robert/django/uploads" #uploads directory   

    <Directory /home/robert/django/uploads>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/robert/django/project>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```